# How save work document in .pdf format in C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I replace the fields in word template with some values using C#, then I need to save the word document as .pdf file. I am able to save it as a .doc file but not .pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell it the new format instead of just a new name. Changing the string name will still try to save it as a word doc, but then the `.pdf` extension will have Word trying to open your (still Word) document as a pdf.

```
wordDoc.SaveAs(@"C:\Documents\myFile.pdf", WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say need some 3rd part libs to save as a pdf file.